# How to disable @html.dropdownlist option label in .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, html-select, disabled-input

View Markup :

`@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.entityType, ViewBag.entityType as SelectList, "Select Type", new { @class = "custom-select"})`

This is the dropdown list in .NET and "select Type" is the option label.

My expectation : I want to disable "Select Type" option label. how can I do this ?

Thanks in advance who's help me.

Regards:
PHioNiX

Comment: Do you want to hide the label or show it but with disabled appearance?

Comment: i want to show this label as disable.

Answer (score 1):

> My expectation : I want to disable "Select Type" option label. how can
> I do this ?

Well,it can be implemented using couple of ways. However, the most easiest and efficient way is, we would check `SelectList` by its `class name` in your scenario it would be `@class = "custom-select"` and set the property as we expect here, disable to be more specific. Just like below:

```
$('.custom-select option:contains("Select Type")').attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

**Note:** Here, `.custom-select` is your class name, we are checking for `Select Type` and finally setting the attribute `disabled`. We are done. Why its efficient, because looping always cost a lot. We are not using loop here which always has `Big 0` impact.

**Complete Solution:**

Model:

```
public class EntityTypeModel
    {
        
        public string? entityType { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Create()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> entityTypeList = new List<SelectListItem>();
            entityTypeList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Entity-Type-C#", Value = "Entity-Type-C#" });
            entityTypeList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Entity-Type-SQL", Value = "Entity-Type-SQL" });
            entityTypeList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Entity-Type-Asp.net core", Value = "Entity-Type-Asp.net core" });
            ViewBag.entityType = entityTypeList;
            return View();
        }
```

View:

```
@model DotNet6MVCWebApp.Models.EntityTypeModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h4>Entity Type Dropdown</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="entityType" class="control-label"></label>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.entityType, @ViewBag.entityType as SelectList, "Select Type", new { @class = "custom-select"})
            <span asp-validation-for="entityType" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@section scripts {
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.custom-select option:contains("Select Type")').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        });
    </script>
}
```

Output:

[image]

**Update:**

Another thing you can do is: You can set your `"Select Type"` text from the backend like this way:

```
entityTypeList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Select Type", Value = "Select Type" });
```

and then you can check if the the user has selected `Select Type` in that case you can update `ModelState` with the error message as below:

```
if (EntityTypeModel.entityType.Contains("Select Type"))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Entity Type should not be Select Type");
            }
```

Comment: hlo greeting sir, your idea is good but in my view have multiple dropdown and it's not possible to i can apply this way on every single dropdown is any way to disable dropdown's first value for all dropdown ? @Md Farid Uddin Kiron

Comment: You have shared your issue with one dropdown so the solution was made on that. If you have multiple dropdown, no worries, post new question with, exact scenario and code snippet new solution will be provided.